# Show three column after match rule in cycle

Tags: regex, awk

Is it possible with awk, to print the three columns following the column matching the substring "eq"?

I have the following file variable and values

```
number1 name eq a 1 2 3 4 5 eq b 1 2 3 4 eq c 1 2 3 4 5 
number2 name eq a 1 2 3 4 5 eq b 1 2 3 4
number3 name eq a 1 2 3 4 5 eq b 1 2 3 4 eq c 1 2 3 4 5 
number4 name eq a 1 2 3 4 5
number5 name eq a 1 2 3 4 5 eq b 1 2 3 4 eq c 1 2 3 4 5 
....
```

If awk finds the substring "eq" in a column, (lets say `$n`) then print `$1` and `$2` and the three column after find "eq" (`$(n+1)`, `$(n+2)` and `$(n+3)`).

expected output:

```
number1 name a 1 2 3 
number1 name b 1 2 3
number1 name c 1 2 3
number2 name a 1 2 3
number2 name b 1 2 3
number3 name a 1 2 3
....
number5 name c 1 2 3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: To answer your question. Yes it is possible, but we would like to see one of your attempts before we help you out. We are not really a coding service.

Comment: Also, it seems you want the 4 columns following the column matching "eq"

Comment: Suggestion, use a for loop to traverse the fields and an if condition to check for a match.

Comment: Would it be possible to make sure that the file format is fixed regarding the place of eq containing column, then everything becomes absolutely easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attempt the following:

```
awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;++i) if ($i == "eq") print $1,$2,$(i+1),$(i+2),$(i+3),$(i+4)}' file
```